# Represent two models in the same Django template

Tags: python, django

I represented my courses as a list already and then generated the page below for each course. On the same page I want to represent, for that specific course, all `course_category` fields with their specific `lecture_title` and content, etc.

```
def courses(request, slug):
    con = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'courses/courses.html', {'course': con})

class Lecture(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    course_category = models.ForeignKey('CourseCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lecture_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    link = models.URLField(blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to='documents')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lecture_title

class CourseCategory(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_category = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_category

class Course(models.Model):
    study_programme = models.ForeignKey('StudyProgramme', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ects = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])
    description = models.TextField()
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])
    semester = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, "1"),
                                            (2, "2"),
                                            ), default=None)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def _get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.name)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while Course.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
        super().save()
```

```html
{% block body %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ course.study_programme }}</li>
        <li>{{ course.name }}</li>
        <li>{{ course.ects }}</li>
        <li>{{ course.description }}</li>
        <li>{{ course.year }}</li>
        <li>{{ course.semester }}</li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
     <ul>
     {% for c in course.course_category %}
        <li><strong>{{ c.course_category}}</strong></li>
     {% endfor %}
        <li>{{ course.lecture_title }}</li>
        <li>{{ course.content}}</li>

    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) parameter in the Lecture and CourseCategory models:

```
class Lecture(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', related_name='lectures')
    ...
```

In the CourseCategory:

```
class CourseCategory(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='categories')
    ...
```

Also, in the view render, you can put the lectures and categories in the render context, so they will be available in the template (as `courses`, `lectures` and `categories`):

```
def courses(request, slug):
    con = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)
    context = {
        'course': con,
        'lectures': con.lectures.all(),
        'categories': con.categories.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/courses.html', context)
```

Comment: Where does 'lectures = course.lectures.all()' go ? syntax is incorrect. Also, how exactly the view should look ?

Comment: I've edited and removed this misleading example. Now the example provides the full view function. I hope it helps